# Conditional encryption of file configuration file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, encryption

I have a question.
I have a solution with MVC3 progect. I need some configuration of my project for conditional encryption of config files.
Conditions:
If I build a debug version - file is not encrypted.
If I build a release version - file is encrypted.

I find this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx)  but I don't know how it can be automated.
Is there some adjustments of solution properties in VS2010 needed or other?

I want to have 2 related configs. If I made changes in non encrypted config, then after release build I receive new encrypted config with all applied changes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to follow these instructions to encrypt a part of the web.config or app.config

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1155/encrypt-connectionstrings-section-of-webconfig/

OR

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/09/434893.aspx